# asp.net mvc3 to mvc4 conversion exception in only some pages

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am changing an MVC3 app to MVC4(all the proper changes have been done in web.config).  The application is loading fine as are some pages but some pages which were working previously in MVC3 are throwing the same kind of error as below: I have done the references correctly and no code was changed during the conversion process

Can anyone tell me the solution for this error

```
Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'
```

This happens when I call this method in a cshtml like this

```
 @{ Html.RenderAction("GetTestItem", "TestItemsInCart", Model.TestItemsList);}
```

and the GetTestItemmethod is

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetTestItem(TestItemsList test)
        {

            TestViewModel xyzViewModel = new TestViewModel ();
            return PartialView("_TestXyz", xyzViewModel );
        }
```

The method is getting called in the controller and it is returning the result to the view only in the cshtml I am getting the stated exception.

This was working previously in mvc3
Thanks

Comment: check if you are referencing the right assemblies in the web.config

Comment: He is only beginer! why does he needed to improve his rate?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that you need to follow to manually upgrade an existing ASP.NET MVC 3 application to MVC 4: http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806

Also the error message that you are getting indicates that you have some missing closing braces in your Razor view. Make sure you have fixed it or show your Razor view if you expect other people be able to help you.

Comment: Hi My code is just too long to be shown here but anyway I have verified the brackets and as far as the whitepapers are concerned I have followed that and i.e why some pages are working

Comment: No, you haven't written the brackets because the error message you are getting indicates that you haven't done so. If you cannot show your code do not expect me telling you, hey, you have an error on line 45, column 67 of your `~/Views/Home/_FooBar.cshtml` where you forgot a closing brace. If that's what you expected to happen I am afraid that you will be quickly disappointed.

Comment: If that is so then why it is working in mvc3 does that accept with out brackets

Comment: I have no idea, maybe you messed up something during the conversion. Unfortunately I cannot read your mind remotely, not your code. Good luck with solving the issue.

Comment: Hi I did not mess my code if you can't find answer just don't reply and I find your answer as complete mess than my question so don't reply if you don't know or reply in a way that you don't mess others questions.

Comment: I also need to warn you that the way you answer questions will decide on the reply you get so that if the response for a question asked by someone facing a issue is not good then their response will not be good.  Good Luck

Comment: I completely agree with you. Except that you are the one asking a question in this case and you are not showing your code making your question difficult to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check for opened brackets. Any opened bracket { needs to be closed with another bracket }.
Check for naming of the variables.